# Xcode 4 -- make error messages briefer and more to the point?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gcc

I left a method out of a class implementation just now.  Here are the error messages.

```
Incomplete implementation of class '*'
Incomplete implementation of class 'MyClass'

Method definition for '*' not found
Method definition for -'MethodIForgot' not found

Semantic Issue
Incomplete implementation
```

Talk about information overload.  I have three separate error messages, all telling me the same thing.  Furthermore, each message is two lines long.  All I really need is the single message "Method definition for -'MethodIForgot' not found."  The rest is fluff.

Is there any way to cut the messages down to size a bit?

Even a partial reduction would be helpful.  In particular, I could do without the first line of each message, as all the information is there in the second line.

Comment: I know this may be a bit late, but I get this issue when I have defined a method in my interface but not in my implementation file. Never used to tell me about it till I upgrade to the new SDK 5

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered switching to the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html) compiler? It is included with Xcode 4 and it specifically lists [expressive, useful diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html) as one of its primary features.

> In addition to being fast and functional, we aim to make Clang extremely user friendly. As far as a command-line compiler goes, this basically boils down to making the diagnostics (error and warning messages) generated by the compiler be as useful as possible. There are several ways that we do this. This section talks about the experience provided by the command line compiler, contrasting Clang output to GCC 4.2's output in several examples.

Comment: I'm fairly sure those errors are the result of using "Apple LLVM Compiler", the new default with iOS 5, which I'm pretty sure is the same as clang.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's 3 error messages, not 6. The first line of each pair is a category, the second line is the specific error. If you click the disclosure triangles next to the categories, you can get some out of the way.

If you want to disable some errors, look at the Build Settings, where you can enable or disable some warning or error messages.